# Working with Ant and e(fx)clipse

Tags: java, ant, javafx-2, build.xml

I am having some trouble understanding the [first tutorial from the e(fx)clipse website](http://www.efxclipse.org/trac/wiki/Tutorial1#no1). I am stuck on step number 11:

```
Click on the "ant build.xml and run" link in the build section of the editor.
```

They also show a picture:

[image: step 11]

I am very new to this, so if someone would be kind enough to show me how to get to this screen, I would be very thankful.

Comment: As I see, it is just asking you to build your project with what ever build system you have (ANT, MAVEN, GRADLE etc). The example talks about ANT and so build.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you open the build.fxbuild file you should see this UI, not?

Comment: pfff... was looking in build section of ECLIPSE editor like many others.. :( thanks